# pyspark fold method output

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm surprised at this output from `fold`, I can't imagine what it's doing.

I would expect that `something.fold(0, lambda a,b: a+1)` would return the number of elements in `something`, since the fold starts at `0` and adds `1` for each element.

```
sc.parallelize([1,25,8,4,2]).fold(0,lambda a,b:a+1 )
8
```

I'm coming from Scala, where fold works as the way I've described. So how is fold supposed to work in pyspark? Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand what's going on here, let's look at the definition of Spark's `fold` operation.  Since you're using PySpark, I'm going to show the Python version of the code, but the Scala version exhibits the exact same behavior (you can also [browse the source on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8cb23a1f9a3ed08e57865bcb6cc1cc7902881073/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L780)):

```
def fold(self, zeroValue, op):
    """
    Aggregate the elements of each partition, and then the results for all
    the partitions, using a given associative function and a neutral "zero
    value."
    The function C{op(t1, t2)} is allowed to modify C{t1} and return it
    as its result value to avoid object allocation; however, it should not
    modify C{t2}.
    >>> from operator import add
    >>> sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).fold(0, add)
    15
    """
    def func(iterator):
        acc = zeroValue
        for obj in iterator:
            acc = op(obj, acc)
        yield acc
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
    return reduce(op, vals, zeroValue)
```

(For comparison, see the [Scala implementation of `RDD.fold`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8cb23a1f9a3ed08e57865bcb6cc1cc7902881073/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L943)).

Spark's `fold` operates by first folding each partition and then folding the results.  The problem is that an empty partition gets folded down to the zero element, so the final driver-side fold ends up folding one value for *every* partition rather than one value for each *non-empty* partition.  This means that the result of `fold` is sensitive to the number of partitions:

```
>>> sc.parallelize([1,25,8,4,2], 100).fold(0,lambda a,b:a+1 )
100
>>> sc.parallelize([1,25,8,4,2], 50).fold(0,lambda a,b:a+1 )
50
>>> sc.parallelize([1,25,8,4,2], 1).fold(0,lambda a,b:a+1 )
1
```

In this last case, what's happening is that the single partition is being folded down to the correct value, then that value is folded with the zero-value at the driver to yield 1.

It seems that Spark's `fold()` operation actually requires the fold function to be commutative in addition to associative.  There are actually other places in Spark that impose this requirement, such as the fact that the ordering of elements within a shuffled partition can be non-deterministic across runs (see [SPARK-5750](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5750)).

I've opened a Spark JIRA ticket to investigate this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6416.

Comment: thanks for thorough answer, I neglected to consider how the partitioning affects the folding. So to clarify the Scala case, the RDD partitions induce important differences from Scala's typical fold behavior. That is, `List(1,2,3,4).fold(0)((a,b)=> a+1)` will be quite different from Spark's    `sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4)).fold(0)((a,b)=> a+1)`

Comment: @keegan, yep, that's right: the partitioning behavior, plus certain sources of ordering nondeterminism, means that the behavior of Spark's fold will currently not behave like you expect when you use an operator that is not commutative.  To further illustrate this, try the following: In Scala, `Seq(2.0, 3.0).fold(1.0)((a, b) => pow(b, a))` will always return 9.0.  Try the same in Spark: `sc.parallelize(Seq(2.0, 3.0), 2).fold(1.0)((a, b) => pow(b, a))`.  On my multi-core laptop, the Spark version will nondeterministically return either 8.0 or 9.0, depending on which partition completes first.

Answer (score 3):

Lets me try to give simple examples to explain fold method of spark. I will be using pyspark here.

`rdd1 = sc.parallelize(list([]),1)`

Above line is going to create an empty rdd with one partition

`rdd1.fold(10, lambda x,y:x+y)`

> This yield output as 20

`rdd2 = sc.parallelize(list([1,2,3,4,5]),2)`

Above line is going to create rdd with values 1 to 5 and will be having a total of 2 partitions

`rdd2.fold(10, lambda x,y:x+y)`

> This yields output as 45

So in above case for sake of simplicity what is happening here is you are having zeroth element as 10. So the sum that you would otherwise get of all numbers in the RDD, is now added by 10(i.e. zeroth element+all other elements => 10+1+2+3+4+5 = 25). Also now we have two partitions(i.e. number of partitions*zeroth element => 2*10 = 20)
Final output that fold emits is 25+20 = 45

Using similar process its clear why the fold operation on rdd1 yielded 20 as output.

Reduce fails when we have empty list something like `rdd1.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y)`

> ValueError: Can not reduce() empty RDD

Fold can be used if we think we can have empty list in the rdd
`rdd1.fold(0, lambda x,y:x+y)`

> As expected this will yield output as 0.